# populate text with three lists value each item of lists fill one text and loop on it

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

My question is about 3 lists and one test i want to populate this text with values of lists in order of values and save each text change in variable (python) each list have 8 values in it.
text: var valueinlist1/n speed valueinlist3/n name valueinlist2

```py
lis1=[999L, 1020L, 1041L, 1062L, 1083L, 1104L, 2010L, 2020L]
lis2=[u'10.0.123.0', u'10.100.1.0', u'10.22.16.0', u'10.22.32.0', u'10.22.45.0', u'10.22.42.0', u'10.1.1.0', u'20.0.0.0']
lis3=[25L, 24L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L]
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried. And a question.

Comment: We don't do homework.

Comment: Yeah, not in the comments. Please update your question with your code.

Comment: @jack, do you have more details for this question? Should this be closed if you are not able to provide additional information?